# Command for both bold and colored text

Tags: color, bold

Every time I want a **bold text**, I want it colored blue. Currently, I am using:

```
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{some bold and colored text}}
```

To save time, I can define a command to do both at once. How can I do it?

Comment: `\newcommand\bluebf[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}` ? This is \bluebf{blue bold text}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply

```
\newcommand\boldblue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit how `1` and `#1` works there? Your solution worked for me, but my attept was `\newcommand{\boldblue}{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{}}` and gave me a compile error and I'm trying to understand how that `1` and `#1` that solves the problem.

Comment: `1` means that the macro `\boldblue` will have one argument*. Later `#1` is a reference for the first argument of `\boldblue`.

* by the way: `[1]` means that this is an optional argument of `\newcommand`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use font-switching commands within `\DeclareTextFontCommand`, here:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\bblue}{\color{blue}\bfseries}
```